# Django selection form from model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Okay, so I've been stuck for a couple of weeks now working on this label system for work.

I've created a django website that enables customers to translate labels for us. I'm creating a form in which a customer chooses the item code that they wish to create a corresponding translation to. This means the form get's it's choice data from the model. When an item code is selected, I want to be able to grab the selected item code and reverse the user into the url matching that item code.

Currently I am using a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to get the data from the model. This works and I am able to display the data in the HTML form. However I am not able to grab the data with `cleaned_data` as it just returns the entire queryset request.

Which means I am getting the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /labelcreator/
Reverse for 'create_label' with keyword arguments '{'pk': <QuerySet [<Label: 13272432 Collar>]>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['labelcreator\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/create_label\\/$']
```

Please see the code below.

**forms.py**

```
class LabelListForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Label.objects.all(), label="")
```

**models.py**

```
class Label(models.Model):
    item_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    label_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    label_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "label"
        verbose_name_plural = "labels"

    def submit(self):
        self.submitted_date = timezone.now()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('create_label', kwargs={'pk'. self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.item_code, self.item_description)
```

**views.py**

```
class LabelListView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = LabelListForm
    template_name = 'labelcreator/overview_create.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.cleaned_data['item']
            return reverse('labelcreator:create_label', kwargs={'pk': item})
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**template**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'labelcreator/css/overview_edit_master.css' %}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group" id="productGroup">
                          <label for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Choose Product...</label>
                          {{ form.as_p }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-1 pull-right">Create 
Label</button>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using a multiplechoice field here. You want to choose a single label, then redirect to its create_label page; you should use a ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Yes, that seems pretty obvious to me now. I have corrected this. Though I am still not able to get the information that I need from the **cleaned_data**